# Json to Java List: Removing space between Objects outside the quotes

Tags: java, json

I am trying to use an online API to retrieve data.

After I get the result in JSON format I tried to convert it into a Java List, but the output I want is not coming as I desire.

Can someone help me out in this task?

Comment: You're using an existing library right? If so say which one it is and show your code, otherwise check out the existing Java JSON parsing libraries

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: yeah I am using HolidayApi

Comment: this is my first time using stackoverflow can you tell me how to show a whole code or how to upload a file

Comment: Copy the code, click on edit question, paste your code right below where your already existing question ends, select the code you just copied and press ctrl+k amd save the edit

Comment: when you retrieve the data, have you tried using something like Postman to initially analyse the payload. Perhaps start there.

Comment: Sorry for the late response..it was running fine. I was messing up with one of the URL spots which was creating spaces between the JSON objects

Answer (score 0):

I am a new developer but I can suggest since you are not getting the desired output maybe you can use a stringbuilder and a buffered reader to read the JSON and turn it into a string.

I hope that helps I am not sure this is the right answer but I can only think of this.